# JDBC + Swing: Not able to get table contents

Tags: java, mysql, swing, search, jdbc

I am learning JDBC, completely new to it. I know MySQL very well. I have a search form in my applet (tab 2), where I search for food. And when I click search, I want it to search for the exact food from the Database and return the table contents of that particular row alone. But I am not getting any result. Only an empty frame opens. But when I put the query as "SELECT * FROM table", I am getting the complete table. But I want only one row, the one that is searched for. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong? Here's my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import com.mysql.jdbc.*;

    public class Tryout extends JFrame  implements ActionListener {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            final Vector columnNames = new Vector();
            final Vector data = new Vector();

            private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
            private JPanel inputpanel;
            private JPanel searchpanel;
            public String s;

            public Tryout()  {          
                    inputpanel = createPage1();
                    searchpanel = createPage2();
                    tabbedPane.addTab("Input Form", inputpanel);
                    tabbedPane.addTab("Search Form", searchpanel);
                    this.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);           
            }

            public JPanel createPage1()  {          
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                //Some code
                return panel;            
            }

            public JPanel createPage2() {      

                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0.5;
                    JLabel region = new JLabel("Enter Region"); 
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    panel.add(region, c);
                    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
                    c.gridx = 1;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    panel.add(field, c);
                    JButton search = new JButton("SEARCH");               
                    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
                    c.gridx = 2;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    panel.add(search, c);
                    s = field.getText();
                    search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                        try{
                        Connection con = null;
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/delikat", "root", "");
                        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = ?");
statement.setString(1,s);
ResultSet rs= (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery();
                        ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
                        int columns = md.getColumnCount();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                        columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
                        }
                        while (rs.next()) {
                        Vector row = new Vector(columns);
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                        row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                        }
                        data.addElement( row );
                        }
                        rs.close();
                        statement.close();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {}
                        JFrame tab=new JFrame();
                        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
                        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
                        tab.add( scrollPane );
                        tab.setVisible(true);
                        tab.setSize(300,100);
                        }
                        });
                    return panel;
            }

            public static void main(String args[]) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    Tryout ex = new Tryout();
                                    ex.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                    ex.setSize(500,500);
                                    ex.setVisible(true);
                            }
                    });
            }       
    }
```

Here is my table:

[image: Table Structure]

Also, I am trying to display the table in the panel itself below the search form but it gives error when I add

```
panel.add(scrollpane);
```

How do I rectify this problem too?

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem the SQL or your GUI code? Just add a println() statement to the query to verify if the model is being created. Also, you should be using a JDialog (not a JFrame) for a popup window. An application should only have a single main JFrame.

Comment: The problem here mainly is the SQL.

Comment: So then get rid of all the Swing code and post your SSCCE that shows how you are building and executing the SQL. You can't solve the problem unless you isolate the problem. People have given you advice on using a PrepearedStatement. All you do is say it doesn't work yet you haven't even posted the code you are using. We can't guess what your are doing.

Comment: I've updated my code, the one using PreparedStatement. I googled about PreparedStatements too. Okay, my query is right. It works fine in mysql compiler. So, I am not able to still figure out where I am going wrong with the code. I've done everything you all said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic debugging. Did you display the value of "s" that is being used in the PreparedStatement?

```
s = field.getText();
```

From what I can see, this statement is executed when you build the GUI which means nothing because the user hasn't even entered any text into this text field.

That statement needs to be executed when you actually invoke the SQL.

Comment: Wait, I have a text field. I am entering something, I storing that value in the 's' variable. And then I am using it in the query. But according to the preparedstatement thing, Stefan asked me to use the "?" mark alone. Neverthless, I tried both. Same thing, tables with field names but not the values.

Comment: Okay, when I put the query as "SELECT * FROM delicious where name = 'Tandoori Roti'" directly, it gives me the correct output. So the problem is with s=field.getText(); how should I place it and where?

Comment: Okay, I placed it inside the try statement and I got my output. THANKS A TON :)

Answer (score 3):

What Sudhanshu means is:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.preparedStatement("SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = ?");
statement.setString(1,s);
ResultSet rs= (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: I did this, and I got error in the ResultSet line. It says st doesn't exist. So I changed statement to st, and then it still gave error asked me to remove that arguement from executeQuery. Still didn't get what I wanted. :(

Comment: @trollster can you please quickly check some tutorial on use of PreparedStatement, its a simple stuff?

Comment: Yes, I checked with PreparedStatement just now. Updated my code to this: PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = s");
                 statement.setString(1,s);
                 ResultSet rs= (ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(); Still not getting.

Comment: Wait let me do some more research myself.

Comment: No!!! not "SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = s" Please write "SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = ?"
The question mark is absolutly necessary...

Comment: Adding the question only gives the field names : id, name, etc. Not the result under it :( Damn. I am trying every possible thing. Is the loop fine?

Comment: Still didn't succeed. I am getting an empty frame. Can you please try out with the database and eclipse and tell me?

Answer (score 2):

Enclose name is quotes if its of type string (varchar). Better use PreparedStatement in such cases.

Comment: Can you please post that line? I can't get you.

Comment: Its the SELECT with WHERE clause. Use PreparedStatement instead of Statement. The value of s has to be in quotes.

Comment: When I do this: ResultSet rs= (ResultSet) st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM delicious WHERE name = 's'");  I get a frame with the field names but not the values

Comment: No, it should be "select * from delicious where name = ' " + s + "'"

Comment: I did this and it didn't work: PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs= (ResultSet) st.executeQuery( "select * from delicious where name = ' " + s + "'");

Comment: If you are using quotes use Statement. Or use PreparedStatement as given by Stefan.